# chained std::bind compile error with VS2015

Tags: c++11, c++14, std-function, stdbind

I'm using VS2015 and I'm playing with `std::function` and `std::bind` I found a strange errors.

I have a 2 chained bind operation:

```
int main()
{


    auto func1 = [](int i) -> int {
        return i + 1;
    };

    auto func2 = [](float f, function<int(int)>&& func) -> float {
        return f + func(f);
    };


    auto func2_instance = std::bind(func2, std::placeholders::_1, func1);

    cout << func2_instance(0.2) << endl;

    auto func3 = [](double d, function<float(float)>&& func)->double {
        return d + func(d);
    };
   //doesn't work
auto func3_instance = std::bind(func3, std::placeholders::_1, std::move(func2_instance));
  //works
auto func3_instance = std::bind(func3, std::placeholders::_1, [funcmv = std::move(func2_instance)](float a)->float{
        return funcmv(a);
    });

    func3_instance(0.2);


}
```

the error I got is related to line `func3_instance(0.2)`

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits(1468): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
```

Could you please help? What I miss related to `std::bind`?

Merci in advance.

Comment: maybe you try change `std::bind` to some lambda expression? And please... use `std::`

Comment: Nested bind expressions are eagerly evaluated; see [`std::is_bind_expression`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/is_bind_expression) and [`boost::protect`](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/#bind.purpose.using_nested_binds_for_function_) for details.

Comment: @21koizyd I don't understand what do you mean!

Comment: @ildjarn I try 
     ` namespace std {
    template<>
        struct is_bind_expression<decltype(func2_instance)> : public 
   true_type {};
   }`
same error. 
I think the problem come from `func3_instance` invocation. like it can't find the right function.

Comment: read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14) and maybe that help. Next advise is don't use `-> (type)` if you don't really need

Comment: @dectroo : I think you want to avoid the eager evaluation, not force it.

Comment: `bind` whose argument is another `bind` invocation behaves somewhat counter-intuitively. `func3_instance(x)` doesn't mean `func3(x, func2_instance)` - it means `func3(x, func2_instance(x))`. A way to think of it is that nested `bind` expression shares the placeholders with the outer `bind`, and they are substituted at the same time. In your example, you effectively have `bind(func3, _1, bind(func2, _1, func1))` - both instances of `_1` get substituted at the same time, they are not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add code, stolen from here:
[Why is there no std::protect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519087/why-is-there-no-stdprotect)

```
template<typename T>
struct protect_wrapper : T
{
    protect_wrapper(const T& t) : T(t) {}
    protect_wrapper(T&& t) : T(std::move(t)) {}
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_bind_expression< typename std::decay<T>::type >::value,
    T&& >::type
protect(T&& t)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_bind_expression< typename std::decay<T>::type >::value,
    protect_wrapper<typename std::decay<T>::type > >::type
protect(T&& t)
{
    return protect_wrapper<typename std::decay<T>::type >(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

and modify your line to:

```
auto func3_instance = std::bind(func3, std::placeholders::_1, protect( func2_instance));
```

the code works ( for me ).

Comment: I like this answer, but it would be even better with the explanation from @IgorTandetnik of what is actually happening.

Comment: @rex: Yes, it would be. But I did not want copy collogues answers in my one... if Igor like he is wellcome to add the comment to my answer. As you already did your comment will point to the explanation...

Comment: Thank @Klaus your `template<> protect()` function solve the problem. Even i don't really understand the reason I'm still learning.
Also `std::ref` solve the issue. As I read from the link you past, `std::ref` can be a good replacement to `protect`function  except it doesn't accpet rvalue and rvalue reference.